# What is the purpose of the 400 kΩ resistor in the 7 V positive reference circuit of the LTZ1000?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, voltage-reference

This circuit is from the datasheet of the famous [LTZ1000](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltz1000.pdf) voltage reference:

[image]

Can anyone explain in detail how the circuit works? Especially the 400 kΩ effect; what is the benefit of the 400 kΩ resistor?

Answer (score 1):

It provides temperature stability to meet the 0.05ppm/°C Drift specification. Source: page 5 of the datasheet.

Comment: I checked page 5 of the datasheet and could not find where it explains that the 400k ohm resistor provides the temperature stability to achieve the 0.05 ppm/°C drift.

Comment: From page 5, first line under the schematic: "*PROVIDES TEMPERATURE COMPENSATION, DELETE FOR LTZ1000A". The "0.05 ppm/°C drift" comes from the device specification. The resistor is how you achieve that.

Comment: Apart from achieving the "0.05 ppm/°C drift", does the absence of the 400kΩ resistor affect the 7.02V voltage to be generated by the LTZ1000 reference?

Comment: @jsuarezbaron IDK and I don't have time to look into it. But without even thinking about it, why wouldn't you include it without out any thought? I guess if your in the quantities of > 10 million's, shaving off an SMD resistor might be worth the increased temp drift...